# HTML/PHP Form doesn't sent data to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm new to PHP so this is  new to me. Anyway I'm creating a site so I can access my receipes online.

This is the form:

```
<form action="Form.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">
<h1><a href="index.html">Receita</a>
    <span>Aqui podes adicionar uma nova receita</span>
</h1>
<label>
    <span>Titulo :</span>
    <input id="titulo" type="text" size="20" maxlength="100" name="titulo" placeholder="Introduza o Titulo" />
</label>

<label>
    <span>Categoria :</span><select  maxlength="10" name="categoria">
    <option value="categoria">--- Seleccione aqui a Categoria ---</option>
    <option name=" " value="sopa">Sopa</option>
    <option name="entrada" value="entrada">Entrada</option>
    <option name="carne" value="carne">Carne</option>
    <option name="peixe" value="peixe">Peixe</option>
    <option name="salada" value="salada">Salada</option>
    <option name="sobremesa" value="sobremesa">Sobremesa</option>
    </select>

</label>

<label>
    <span>Ingredientes :</span>
    <textarea id="ingredientes" size="20" maxlength="1000" name="ingredientes" placeholder="Introduza os ingredientes"></textarea>
</label> 
<label>
    <span>Preparação :</span>
    <textarea id="preparacao" size="20" maxlength="1000" name="preparacao" placeholder="Introduza o modo de preparação"></textarea>
</label> 
<label>
    <span>Notas :</span>
    <textarea id="notas" size="20" maxlength="1000" name="notas" placeholder="Aqui pode adicionar uma nota"></textarea>
</label> 
<label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Enviar" /> 
</label>   

</form>
```

This is the code to handle the form:

```
<?php
// processing form values


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$ingredientes = $_POST['ingredientes'];
$preparacao = $_POST['preparacao'];
$notas = $_POST['notas'];


if(!empty($titulo) && !empty($categoria) && !empty($ingredientes) && !empty($preparacao) && !empty($notas)){

    include('connection.php');

    mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO receita(Titulo,Categoria,Ingredientes,Preparacao,Notas) VALUES ('$titulo','$categoria','$ingredientes','$preparacao','$notas')");
    $registered = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
    echo $registered." row is affected, everything worked fine!";
}else{
    echo "Please fill all values on the form";
}

}else{

echo "No form has been submitted";

}

?>
```

**And what happens is that if I input something like this it doesn't work:**

Titulo:Açorda de camarao

Categoria: Peixe

Ingredientes: 800 g de camarao; 4 dentes de alho; 1 ramo de salsa ou coentros; 3 ovos inteiros; 1.5 dl de Azeite; 1.5 pão por pessoa; sal; piri-piri

Preparação: Coze-se o camarão com sal e piri-piri e reserva-se a agua. De seguida demolha-se o pão na agua do camarão. Aquece-se o azeite com os alhos e os coentros e de seguida junta-se o camarão e por ultimo o pão. Mexe-se tudo para cozer o pão e ganhar consistencia. Por ultimo junta-se os ovos e envolve-se tudo.

Nota: Receita para 4 pessoas

**But if I input like this it works:**

Titulo:gfdsfdsa

Categoria: Peixe

Ingredientes: hudsbfbdsf fdsfidsfidsfsd, fdsjifjdsifdis 0palpdsandnsaud jkdosakodsakodmnsa jidsjaidsa

Preparação: nfjdbshfbhdbjfdjs dsajijdisandiabuu fjndoisjfojidsanfds

Nota: fbhdubsufbndsnfs

**My database table:**

```
Nome    Tipo    Agrupamento (Collation) Atributos   Nulo    Omissao Extra
```

1   ID    bigint(50)    Não    None     AUTO_INCREMENT  Muda Muda   Elimina
2   Titulo varchar(100) utf8_general_ci     Não None    Muda Muda   Elimina 
3   Categoria varchar(10)   utf8_general_ci     Não None        Muda Muda
4   Ingredientes varchar(1000)  utf8_general_ci     Não None        Muda 
5   Preparacao varchar(1000)    utf8_general_ci     Não None        Muda Muda   6   Notas varchar(1000) utf8_general_ci     Não None        Muda Muda

Sorry if this post its to long. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

There's probably a special character in the input that's causing a syntax error in the query.

You need to either escape your input before substituting it into the query. Add this after `include ('connection.php');`

```
$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $titulo);
$categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $categoria);
// and so on for all the other variables
```

or (better) use a prepared statement. Use this in place of your call to `mysqli_query`:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "INSERT INTO receita(Titulo,Categoria,Ingredientes,Preparacao,Notas) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $titulo, $categoria, $ingredientes, $preparacao, $notas);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$registered = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
```

Comment: @BryanWay He's using mysqli in the question. I didn't change that.

Comment: Sorry guys but i'm kinda lost. The code above from Barmar do i add it, or replace it? and where? sorry, noob here :p

Comment: I've added more explanation, I hope it's enough. It should be clear if you understand what these things do.

Comment: I did what you said and still doesn't work, don't know if i'm doing anything wrong...